# Styling OssLicensesMenuActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-theme, android-styles

I am using a Google library called [play-services-plugins](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/tree/master/oss-licenses-plugin) to [include Open Source Notices](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource) on my app.

I could implement it with no problem, but I have no idea how I can style the activity that displays the license.

In my code, I start the activity by calling `startActivity(Intent(this, OssLicensesMenuActivity::class.java))`

Since `OssLicensesMenuActivity` is an Activity class, I manage to style like this:

**styles.xml:**

```xml
<style name="LicensesTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```xml
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesMenuActivity"
    android:theme="@style/LicensesTheme" />
```

This works like a charm, but this activity just displays all the libraries I'm using.
There is a second activity that displays the licence and that's the one I can't figure out how to style. The problem I'm facing is that the code from `OssLicensesMenuActivity` is obfuscated and I can't find the name and package of the activity class I want to style.

Anyone knows how I can solve this problem?

Just to it's easier to check, the obfuscated code from `OssLicensesMenuActivity` is the following:

```java
package com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import androidx.loader.content.Loader;
import com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepForSdk;
import com.google.android.gms.internal.oss_licenses.zzc;
import com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.R.id;
import com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.R.layout;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class OssLicensesMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<List<zzc>> {
    private static String zzx;
    private ListView zzy;
    private ArrayAdapter<zzc> zzz;
    private boolean zzaa;
    private zze zzp;
    private Task<String> zzab;
    private com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.zzc zzo;

    public OssLicensesMenuActivity() {
    }

    @KeepForSdk
    protected final void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle var1) {
        super.onCreate(var1);
        this.zzo = com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.zzc.zza(this);
        this.zzaa = fileExistsAndNotEmpty(this, "third_party_licenses") && fileExistsAndNotEmpty(this, "third_party_license_metadata");
        Intent var3;
        if (zzx == null && (var3 = this.getIntent()).hasExtra("title")) {
            zzx = var3.getStringExtra("title");
            Log.w("OssLicensesMenuActivity", "The intent based title is deprecated. Use OssLicensesMenuActivity.setActivityTitle(title) instead.");
        }

        if (zzx != null) {
            this.setTitle(zzx);
        }

        if (this.getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        if (this.zzaa) {
            zzh var10001 = com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.zzc.zza(this).zzb();
            String var4 = this.getPackageName();
            zzh var2 = var10001;
            this.zzab = var10001.doRead(new zzk(var2, var4));
            this.getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(54321, (Bundle)null, this);
            this.zzab.addOnCompleteListener(new zzp(this));
        } else {
            this.setContentView(layout.license_menu_activity_no_licenses);
        }
    }

    public static void setActivityTitle(@NonNull String var0) {
        zzx = var0;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting(
        otherwise = 2
    )
    @KeepForSdk
    static boolean fileExistsAndNotEmpty(@NonNull Context var0, @NonNull String var1) {
        InputStream var2 = null;

        try {
            Resources var3;
            String var4 = (var3 = var0.getResources()).getResourcePackageName(id.license_list);
            boolean var5 = (var2 = var3.openRawResource(var3.getIdentifier(var1, "raw", var4))).available() > 0;
            return var5;
        } catch (IOException | NotFoundException var13) {
        } finally {
            if (var2 != null) {
                try {
                    var2.close();
                } catch (IOException var12) {
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    @KeepForSdk
    public final boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem var1) {
        if (var1.getItemId() == 16908332) {
            this.finish();
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(var1);
        }
    }

    @KeepForSdk
    public final void onDestroy() {
        this.getSupportLoaderManager().destroyLoader(54321);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @KeepForSdk
    public final Loader<List<zzc>> onCreateLoader(int var1, Bundle var2) {
        return this.zzaa ? new zzo(this, com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.zzc.zza(this)) : null;
    }

    @KeepForSdk
    public final void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<zzc>> var1, List<zzc> var2) {
        this.zzz.clear();
        this.zzz.addAll(var2);
        this.zzz.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @KeepForSdk
    public final void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<zzc>> var1) {
        this.zzz.clear();
        this.zzz.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class zza extends ArrayAdapter<zzc> {
        zza(Context var2) {
            OssLicensesMenuActivity.this.zzo;
            int var10002 = com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.zzc.zza(OssLicensesMenuActivity.this.zzp);
            OssLicensesMenuActivity.this.zzo;
            super(var2, var10002, com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.zzc.zzb(OssLicensesMenuActivity.this.zzp), new ArrayList());
        }

        public final View getView(int var1, View var2, ViewGroup var3) {
            if (var2 == null) {
                OssLicensesMenuActivity.this.zzo;
                LayoutInflater var10000 = OssLicensesMenuActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                zze var6 = OssLicensesMenuActivity.this.zzp;
                LayoutInflater var4 = var10000;
                XmlResourceParser var7 = var6.zzg.getXml(com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.zzc.zza(var6));
                var2 = var4.inflate(var7, var3, false);
            }

            OssLicensesMenuActivity.this.zzo;
            ((TextView)var2.findViewById(com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.zzc.zzb(OssLicensesMenuActivity.this.zzp))).setText(((zzc)this.getItem(var1)).toString());
            return var2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just do the same for "OssLicensesActivity" as you did for "OssLicensesMenuActivity" in the Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesActivity"
            android:theme="@style/LicensesTheme" />
```

This should style the "second activity that displays the licence".

Comment: It worked perfectly!! Sorry that it took so long for me to reply and accept as the right answer, but although it got some upvotes, I wanted to check it myself and I was not being able to test it